# Jersey response very slow

Tags: json, performance, servlets, jersey, response

I am using jersey for REST service, and during measuring request time I encountered a delay in the response which seems to come from jersey itself.

While the computation of the request is about 8 seconds (testsystem), the time until jersey delivers the request is additionally 12 seconds. The 8 seconds are measured from the first jersey "Server in-bound request" after the request ist build in our code:

```
Response.ok( entity ).build( );
```

Then, some magic in jersey happens and this magic seems to last 12 sec until the " Server out-bound response" log appears and the json stuff appears on the console. cURL says, that the request lasted 20secs. The resonse contains 32 more or less big json data strings.

I have already turned off the link and logging filter in web.xml, no improvements.

I have no idea where to start searching for. Thanks for your ideas!

We

Comment: you would need to add more details if you want concrete answer; anyways, you can try serializing your entity by yourself (and maybe include it as byte[] or stream in the response) if you think that this is a main problem. And trying without entity to have prove that it is really about it is a first think I would do.

Comment: OK, some more information: I added a log into the link filter, which seems to last 87ms, which I think is ok for a rather slow test system. I suspect the com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature may be the probleme here....

Comment: can you try returning empty response and rerun your test? Or share more info about entity (data type definition and corresponding values)..

Comment: Less data (or even nothing) speeds up the response; returning nothing makes the response finishing after the response.build() above.

Comment: The entity type is generic, that is the code for it is generated during runtime. Only thing i can say is that it may have several "normal" attributes and @References, where the references are converted to a URI in the JSON response.

Comment: ok. Next step would be watching how long takes entity generation compared to its serialization.

Comment: Maybe a bit late, but if you were using URL to create those URIs, they may have been doing dns checks.